# Error occured in Retrofit connection

Tags: java, android, http-post

My interface

```
@POST("/insert.php")
void  login(Callback<Response> callback);
```

Java code

```
Retrofit adapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                       .baseUrl(ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
                       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                       .build(); //Finally building the adapter

Register_Retrofit api = adapter.create(Register_Retrofit.class);


api.login( new Callback<Response>() {
    public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {

    }

    public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {

    }

});
```

Comment: can you clarify "Error"? what do you mean by 'Error'? compile time? runtime? stacktrace? is it just that your code doesn't function the way you expect it? what did you expect it to do and what does it (not) do?

Comment: what was the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your login method return void, so you need to define it like this:

```
@POST("/insert.php")
Call<Void> login();
```

Then, to call the login method try this:

```
Retrofit adapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                       .baseUrl(ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
                       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                       .build(); //Finally building the adapter

Register_Retrofit api = adapter.create(Register_Retrofit.class);
Call<Void> loginCall = api.login();
loginCall.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() { 
     public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) { 
          ... 
     } 

     public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) { 
          ... 
     }
});
```